# Winemaking Clubs in Greater DC area

Tags: wine

Is anyone aware of wine making clubs in the greater Washington, DC area?  I'd prefer Maryland, but beggars can't be choosers.  I've checked Winemaker Magazine's list of clubs, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any strictly wine making clubs but I know I've talked to some people who make wine, cider, mead and a lot of other things that aren't beer at some of the local homebrewing clubs.

I'd recommend checking out [BURP](http://brew.burp.org/default.aspx) and the [DC Homebrewers Club](http://blog.dchomebrewers.com/). Both clubs are filled with lots of fantastic people.

Answer (score 1):

I would go by Maryland Homebrew in Columbia and ask there.